# .permissions missing from GuildMember causing weird error Discord.js

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I am using Discord.js with TypeScript and am running into some strange errors when I try to access the permissions of a member.

```js
export const Ban: Command = {
  name: "ban",
  description: "Ban a user from the server.",
  options: [
    { type: 6, name: "target", description: "The user to be banned." },
    { type: 3, name: "reason", description: "Reason for the ban." },
  ],
  type: "CHAT_INPUT",
  run: async (_client: Client, interaction: CommandInteraction) => {
    const guild = interaction.guild;
    if (!guild) {
      interaction.reply("This command must be used in a guild!");
      return;
    }
    const userMember = await guild.members.fetch(interaction.user);
    console.log(userMember);
  }
}
```

The variable `userMember` apparently has type `GuildMember` however, when logged, it is missing a `.permissions` value.
If I change the last line to `console.log(userMember.permissions)`, TypeScript does not complain, but I get a weird error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at GuildMemberRoleManager.get cache [as cache] (/<mypath>/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberRoleManager.js:36:101)
    at GuildMember.get permissions [as permissions] (/<mypath>/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildMember.js:262:39)
    at Object.run (/<mypath>/src/commands/mod/ban.ts:33:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The error appears to be coming somewhere from Discord.js itself. Any ideas on what to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const userMember = await guild.members.fetch(interaction.user);
```

The fetch option is either snowflake or null, not an user.
You can read about fetching guildMember [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch)
or you just access member who used the slash command through interaction:

```js
const userMember = interaction.member;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ended up using `interaction.memberPermissions` exactly what I needed!